# how to go from http to https, certificate already installed and https is working

Tags: laravel, apache

if someone directly enters www.myapp.com the browser will take them to http://www.myapp.com

myapp is configured to work with https so if we enter manually https://www.myapp.com then there are no problems laravel generates https urls correctly?

how do I get browser to go to https when user just enters www.myapp.com instead of browser taking them to the http?

Where is the most elegant place to make this happen?

Comment: What kind of webserver do you host? Apache, NginX?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a middleware something like this:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

      if (!app()->environment('local')) {
            // for Proxies
        Request::setTrustedProxies([$request->getClientIp()]);

        if (!$request->isSecure()) {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }
    }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include this in your ***.htaccess*** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I get this error:

The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

laravel already comes with .htaccess, where in this file do I place this, at top or bottom, perhaps that is important?

Comment: @nikocraft Try placing it on top if that makes any difference! You could also try clearing your browser's cookies and caches!

Answer (score 0):

Add `\URL::forceScheme('https');` to `AppServiceProvider`

Thats an optional solution.